# How can I create a redirect form

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have create one form, and after someone submits, that form they will be redirected to another page. And the problem that I faced now is after I submit the form goes to a blank page and just loading with black background.

I have tried with http and without http at the front of the redirect link, still fail

```
<?php

$errors = array();

// Check if name has been entered
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Please enter your name';
}
// Check if name has been entered
if (!isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $errors['phone'] = 'Please enter your phone number';
}

// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

//Check if message has been entered
if (!isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $errors['message'] = 'Please enter your message';
}

$errorOutput = '';

if(!empty($errors)){

    $errorOutput .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
    $errorOutput .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';

    $errorOutput  .= '<ul>';

    foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
        $errorOutput .= '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    }

    $errorOutput .= '</ul>';
    $errorOutput .= '</div>';

    echo $errorOutput;
    die();
}
else{
    $response = ['success' => true];
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}



$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $email;
$to = 'support@waveevo.com';  // please change this email id
$subject = 'Contact Enquiry from Pentair Everpure Landing Page';

$body = " From: $name\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$headers = "From: ".$from;


//send the email
$result = '';
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $result .= '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
    $result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
    $result .= 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, you will be redirected to download our brochure!';
    $result .= '</div>';

    echo $result;
    die();
}

$result = '';
$result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
$result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
$result .= 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
$result .= '</div>';

echo $result;
?>
```

My JS query code,

```
 $("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var $ = jQuery;

        var postData = $(this).serializeArray(),
            formURL = $(this).attr("action"),
            $cfResponse = $('#contactFormResponse'),
            $cfsubmit = $("#cfsubmit"),
            cfsubmitText = $cfsubmit.text();

        $cfsubmit.text("Sending...");


        $.ajax(
            {
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    $cfResponse.html(data);
                    $cfsubmit.text(cfsubmitText);
                    $('#contactForm input[name=name]').val('');
                    $('#contactForm input[name=email]').val('');
                    $('#contactForm textarea[name=message]').val('');
                    window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error occured! Please try again");
                }
            });

        return false;

    });
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Put after your "header("location....")" an exit; or die;

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have try it but still faced the same problem.

Comment: what problem you are facing.... can you share it. share you updated code. also share your HTML code.

Comment: @PrathameshDoke Hi sir, thanks for your comment. I have a form, and after submit that form, it should be redirect to another page(Thank you page). but I got error as shown in the image above..

Comment: Looking at your PHP code, it seems your email will never be sent, and your messages never displayed, because you redirect the user and end the script before that code happens. I don't suppose this is what you really intended?

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for your comment. Actually I received the messages in my email.

Comment: That should be impossible, because of `if(!empty($errors)){ ... echo $errorOutput;
    die();
} else{
    header("Location: https://pentairasia.com/index.html");
    die();
}` - the code dies whether it enters the if block or the else block. It will never go past that point. maybe the code you are running is different to the code you've shown us?

Comment: @ADyson hi, sorry my bad.. before I add die(); after the header, I receive the text in my email. Now did not receive it after I add die();...

Comment: well now you know why. A more logical structure would be: `else{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $email;
$to = 'support@waveevo.com';  // please change this email id
$subject = 'Contact Enquiry from Pentair Everpure Landing Page';

$body = " From: $name\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
$headers = "From: ".$from; mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);    header("Location: https://pentairasia.com/index.html");
    die();
} ?>`

Comment: That way the email is sent before you do the redirect and end the script. Be aware of course that if you redirect the user to another page, you cannot also display them a message on the current page - the browser never displays the response from your PHP code, it just receives the redirection header and immediately loads that page instead.

Comment: Also...how are you submitting the form in the first place? The screenshot you showed above looks strange...are you submitting the form via AJAX? If so then the answer below might help you. In that case you _could_ display a confirmation message and then, when the user has dismissed it, use JavaScript to navigate to the new page. You can't do a server-side redirect when you're using AJAX (because the whole point of AJAX is to be able to talk to the server but still _stay on the same page_).

Comment: Hi @ADyson, Im submitting the form by AJAX. Already followed below answer and still receive an error.

Comment: What error, exactly?

Comment: Hi @ADyson it doesn't redirect to the other page, and it shows [success=true] under the button. Btw, I have change the whole code and just use php instead of AJAX.... Thanks for your concern.. :)

Answer (score 1):

When i look at your screenshot, than i'll guess, that you submit your form with ajax.
So thats nonesense to set an redirect in PHP when you submit over an ajax-request.

So the solution is, that you check your ajax response for e.g. success => true and than do an

```
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

=> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

EDIT:
PHP-Response:
Instead of

```
header("Location: https://pentairasia.com/index.html");
die();
```

Write something like

```
$response = ['success' => true];
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

And your JS-Script (for jQuery) could you edit with:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( json ) {
  // CHANGES START*****
  if(json.success) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
  }
  // CHANGES END*****
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have try it and still got error. I have edit my question as per your answer.